# String Comparison : Python

Tags: python, string

I have a group of strings which look like this:

```
M.HpyFIX.dna|GTNAAC
M1.HpyFXIII.dna|CCATC
M.HpyFI.dna|CAGT
M2.HpyFXIII.dna|CCATC
M.HpyFVI.dna|TGCA
M.HpyFVIII.dna|TCNNGA
M.HpyFORFX.dna|CCNNGG
M.HpyFII.dna|TCGA
M.HpyFVII.dna|ATTAAT
M.HpyFXII.dna|GTCA
M.HpyFV.dna|CCGG
M.HpyFXI.dna|CTNAG
M.HpyFIII.dna|GATC
M.HpyFIV.dna|GANTC
```

I wanna compare them only based on the string after the `|` (pipe). I dont want to use `string.strip('|')`. In the above case i would like to get each string one by one and apply the functions I have except for `M1.HpyFXIII.dna|CCATC` and `M2.HpyFXIII.dna|CCATC` which i would like to get into in a temporary list and then apply apply the functions.

The reason I want to use string comparisons is that I am using `ETE` to build phylogenetic trees and its much simpler with string comparisons

Comment: Ok no strip, how about split? (I dont' get it why some people don't want to use certain functions without a reason)

Comment: What would you expect `strip()` to do ? Perhaps you meant `split()` ?

Comment: `split` converts the string into 2 parts and placed into list. Using these lists with the `ETE` tool is a massive headache

Comment: @Beginner I'm not a Python expert but the documentation says that `strip` will remove only leading and trailing characters - it will not remove *inner* characters: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Comment: Further, your question is unclear: what do you mean by "comparing" ? any two string in the list ? what would such a result look like ? output all the "similar" strings ? you should finish your example by providing an expected output (the "input" is not enough!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not `s.split('|')[1]` to get the part of the string after the `|`, then perhaps

```
s[s.index('|')+1:]
```

Which grabs the substring from all characters past the `|` to the end of the string.

I wouldn't call using `split` as above a "massive headache", however, and it's arguably easier to read.

To transform the entire list, you can create a function that does what you want it to do, then use a list comprehension or `map`.

Comment: it throws a `Value Error: substring not found`

Comment: Nevermind, I had a stupid error in the list. It works . Thanks. Accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split() method, and then take the second string in the returned list.

```
_junk, myString = 'M.HpyFIX.dna|GTNAAC'.split('|')
```

Or if you don't want to store it in a string:

```
'M.HpyFIX.dna|GTNAAC'.split('|')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat as csv file with custom delimiter

```
>>> import csv
>>> import collections
>>> with open('in.txt') as in_file:
...     reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter='|')
...     data   = list(reader)  #exhaust generator, convert it to list
...     #now you have loaded your data in two-dimensional array, lets find dups
...     dup_values = [x for x, y in collections.Counter([r[1] for r in data]).items() if y > 1]
...     for r in data:
...             if r[1] in dup_values:
...                     print r
... 
['M1.HpyFXIII.dna', 'CCATC']
['M2.HpyFXIII.dna', 'CCATC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is `str.partition`:

```
x = "M.HpyFIX.dna|GTNAAC"
object, _, sequence = x.partition("|")
print(sequence)
# or grab the third element
print(x.partition("|")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = ['M.HpyFIX.dna|GTNAAC', 'M1.HpyFXIII.dna|CCATC', 'M.HpyFVII.dna|ATTAAT']

nls = [ l.split('|')[1] for l in ls ]
```